# Why is "use strict" a plain string and not a JavaScript reserved keyword?

Tags: javascript

In other words, why is it `'use strict'` instead of `use strict`?

I didn't find an answer to this question here: [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

My guess is that it makes this instruction backwards compatible without needing any transpilation but I can't find any source.

Comment: What answer are you looking for that wasn't already in that question? Also transpilation didn't exist when `'use strict'` was made

Comment: Why it's not a reserved keyword. In other words why `'use strict'` instead of `use strict`?

Comment: When it was introduced it was important that you could add it to a Javascript file and the code in that file could still run in older browsers.

Comment: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/#definition does this help?

Comment: [It's called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14902465/1048572) a "[prologue directive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28802885/1048572)". Also used e.g. for `"use asm;"`

Comment: I believe your guess is correct.

Comment: Thanks, just found the spec of directive prologues here: https://es5.github.io/#x14.1 It doesn't tell much about why they are plain strings though

Comment: I think it might be because keywords aren't a thing without strict mode? http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/#future-reserved-keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's for backwards compatibility. Some sources:

- https://blog.maisie.ink/js-strict-mode/

  > Strict mode had to be an opt-in feature to maintain backwards
  > compatibility with old scripts. Some old scripts relied on features
  > that strict mode deprecated, and thus, would need to run in non-strict
  > mode by default. Additionally, the opt-in syntax `'use strict';` is just
  > a string literal, which allowed new scripts to run in old browsers.
- https://medium.com/jp-tech/introduction-to-strict-mode-in-javascript-fb977bab697c

  > *[Why not change the ECMAScript specification completely instead of
  > introducing an extra "strict mode"?]* Perhaps part of it is to ensure
  > that some backward compatibility between ES5 and the previous version
  > is ES3, partly so that ECMAScript retains simplicity and flexibility
  > from before, rather than being limited by the new rigid added rules
- https://johnresig.com/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/ (John Resig)

  > Note the syntax that’s used to enable strict mode (I love this!). It’s
  > simply a string in a single statement that happens to contain the
  > contents “use strict”. *No new syntax is introduced in order to enable
  > strict mode.* This is huge. This means that you can turn strict mode on
  > in your scripts – today – and it’ll have, at worst, no side effect in
  > old browsers.

  (found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223578/1048572))

Even more authoritative:

- [an email by Waldemar Hartmann](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-May/002590.html) on the es5-discuss mailing list (apparently a precursor to es-dicuss?), found via [those](http://archives.ecma-international.org/2009/TC39/tc39-2009-035.pdf) ancient meeting notes:

  > […] the general concept of the use strict directive was that it generally
  > followed lexical rules of ECMAScript statements and might even appear
  > unquoted in future versions of the language that had opt-in of
  > syntactic extensions.
- the ES5 specification itself [notes on the](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262#sec-14.1)

  > The ExpressionStatement productions of a Directive Prologue are
  > evaluated normally during evaluation of the containing SourceElements
  > production. Implementations may define implementation specific
  > meanings for ExpressionStatement productions which are not a Use
  > Strict Directive and which occur in a Directive Prologue.

  so it's not only backwards-compatible but also forwards-compatible - and this was indeed used for the [`"use asm";` directive](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#validation) later
- the [official paper by the spec authors Allen Wirfs-Brock and Brendan Eich on JavaScript](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3386327) explains the reasoning in detail:

  > An early issue was how the opt-in to strict mode would work. […] One
  > possibility was to use a special form of comment as a directive.
  > However, the ES3.1 working group was reluctant to make comments, of
  > any form, semantically significant because JavaScript minimizers
  > remove comments. Allen Wirfs-Brock observed that the syntax of an
  > ECMAScript *ExpressionStatement* makes any expression, including those
  > that consist of only a literal string constant, into a valid statement
  > as long as it is explicitly or implicitly (via ASI) followed by a
  > semicolon. That means that a statement such as `"use strict";` is
  > syntactically valid ES3 code. Because it is simply a constant value,
  > evaluating it has no side effects in ES3. It is a *no-op*. It appeared
  > quite safe to use such a statement as the opt-in for strict mode as it
  > seemed highly unlikely that any existing JavaScript code would already
  > have used that exact statement form and an ES3 implementation would
  > ignore its presence in any ES5 code that was loaded. The working group
  > adopted that idea. A statement of the form `"use strict";` occurring
  > as the first statement of a script or a function body indicated that
  > the entire script or function should be processed using strict mode
  > semantics.

Comment: I'm not sure loose mode even had reserved keywords? (you didn't say that, btw)

Comment: @evolutionxbox ES3 did have reserved words (keywords), just not future ones.

Answer (score 1):

For backwards compatibility.
Browsers that don't support strict mode will simply ignore the string.